# writing a text file to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, text

I have a text file that contains a sentence in each line. Some lines are also empty.

```
sentence 1
sentence 2
empty line
```

I want to write the content of this file in a csv file in a way that the csv file has only one column and in each row the corresponding sentence is written. This is what I have tried:

```
import csv

f = open('data 2.csv', 'w')
with f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for row in open('data.txt', 'r):
        writer.writerow(row)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data 2.csv')
```

Supposing that I have three sentences in my text file, I want a csv file to have one column with 3 rows. However, when I run the code above, I will get the output below:

```
[1 rows x 55 columns]
```

It seems that each character in the sentences is written in one cell and all sentences are written in one row. How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to load a text file into a single column of a dataframe, one line per dataframe row. It can be done directly:

```
with open(data.txt) as file:
    df = pd.DataFrame((line.strip() for line in file), columns=['text'])
```

You can even filter empty lines at read time with `filter`:

```
with open(data.txt) as file:
    df = pd.DataFrame(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, (line.strip() for line in file)),
                      columns=['text'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you iterate through each character in the text file. Try reading line by line through `readlines()` method:

```py
import csv

f = open('data 2.csv', 'w')
with f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    text_file = open('data.txt', 'r')

    for row in text_file.readlines():
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: The volume of the data is very large and if I write the sentences to a list, the list will get so big that the program can't handle it.

Comment: In your code, you iterate through each character in the text file. Try reading line by line through `readlines()` method

Comment: @BNoor: Hmm... you later want to load it in a pandas dataframe don't you? Where do you think that the dataframe will reside? If the list can exhaust your memory, the dataframe will certainly do it too!

Comment: I want to later convert the csv file to a tfrecord dataset. I can't read the whole data to a list since the volume is very large.